# What do you call 'a person of encyclopedic culture'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Would 'polymath' a correct word to substitute  'a person of "encyclopedic" culture' in

> He is described as an atheist, a materialist, and a person of "encyclopedic" culture.

quoted from 'Creating the Hybrid Intellectual' by Anne Lambright.

Or, as an instance, 'polyhedric' is more suitable?

I'm unsure because Merriam-Webster defines 'polymath' as 'a person of encyclopedic learning', not as 'a person of encyclopedic culture'.

Comment: How would you distinguish between someone of encyclopedic learning and somone of encyclopedic culture? I'm not really sure what the latter would be.

Comment: @England, I, too, do not completely agree with the writer's phrasing, but I just wanted to make sure the writers had used a sloppy wording.

Comment: 'polymath' is it. 'polyhedric' is a perfectly grammatical construction of a new word that makes sense metaphorically, but sounds weird and is rare if at all recognized.

Comment: **polyhedric** *- having the form of a polyhedron; = **polyhedral** adj.* I don't think using it figuratively in this way is credible. It *used* to be used to mean "multi-faceted, having many aspects" (of a complex problem, for example), but that's probably archaic now anyway.

Comment: In Italian the corresponding "poliedrico" is a common and good word for this meaning. Example: http://www.ilfatto.net/news/cultura-eventi/2828-molfetta-leonardo-da-vinci-un-genio-poliedrico or http://aulascienze.scuola.zanichelli.it/2012/05/04/leonardo-in-mostra/

Comment: I would agree with the asker that whoever wrote the original phrase here either did so in a specific context or style where these words have a particular meaning, or that it is simply not very well-worded. As @jwpat7 notes, it is basically an impossible task to find a synonym for a phrase that does not make proper sense.

Comment: I suspect the meaning intended was that the person's breadth of knowledge is so wide and varied it has taken encyclopaedic proportions. "Culture" is often confused with one meaning of *cultura* in Italian; to be educated, erudite and to be knowledgeable about the arts and sciences. A renaissance person (doesn't always have to be a man), in fact.

Answer (score 3):

On brief inspection of the passage (from [page 140](http://books.google.com/books?id=HdDrdKZLL0AC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=Creating+the+Hybrid+Intellectual++Anne+Lambright++atheist++materialist+encyclopedic++culture&source=bl&ots=2B9QOB_of1&sig=fEMWGCQdSrvxXUN8hKyZ3k0LtUE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Mm00UvLiCuKbiAKazICABw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Creating%20the%20Hybrid%20Intellectual%20%20Anne%20Lambright%20%20atheist%20%20materialist%20encyclopedic%20%20culture&f=false) of *Creating the Hybrid Intellectual*, by Anne Lambright) in more context, it is less than clear just what is meant by the phrase *a person of “encyclopedic” culture*.  (*[Encyclopedic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encyclopedic#Adjective)* means “Of or relating to the characteristics of an encyclopedia”, the latter being “A comprehensive reference work ... with in-depth articles ... on a range of subjects, sometimes general, sometimes limited to a particular field”. *[Culture](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culture#Noun)* is  “The arts, customs, and habits that characterize a particular society or nation” or  “The beliefs, values, behaviour and material objects that constitute a people's way of life”.  The question is what the words mean when put together.)

One possibility is a person who gained culture by reading an encyclopedia.  Another, a person whose culture consists of diverse short subjects, like synopses found in typical encyclopedias.  The most charitable cast – a person whose culture is broad, wide-ranging, knowledgeable – also is the most unlikely (*cf* a later phrase, “his incorporation of indigenous culture is decorative”) but were that the intended meaning, words like *[urbane](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/urbane#Adjective)*, *[polished](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polished#Adjective)*, and *[sophisticated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophisticated#Adjective)* would be appropriate.

To divine the actual meaning would require going back to the source from which Lambright quoted the description, either an article of Margot Beyersdorff or the [Arguedas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mar%C3%ADa_Arguedas) novel being discussed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather sexist term that may convey the concept: **[renaissance man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance_Man)**

> Polymath, a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different subject areas

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Renaissance-man?q=renaissance%20man) defines it at

> a man with many talents or areas of knowledge.

While *culture* per se in not mentioned, I believe that a broad cultural command is often part of the concept. The reference to *renaissance* seems to hearken back to the blossoming of both culture and learning during that period (and an admiration of some of the luminaries of the era).

It also could be rendered gender neutral as **renaissance person** or having a **renaissance character**

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in the comments really but just to get an actual answer here, yes *polymath* is a perfectly good substitute. [*Polyhedric*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/polyhedric) is not since that brings to mind someone whose physical appearance is that of a polyhedron, it is a word that describes shapes, not characters. Perhaps, as FumbleFIngers suggested, that was once not the case but a cursory search did not return any examples of this.

I *did* find a [case](http://en.ideas.ie.edu/revista-101/el-hombre-poliedrico-384705/) where it is used in the way you describe (well, *polyhedral* but close enough)  but, to me at least, it sounds really strange and I believe it is simply a direct translation from Spanish.

So, yes, use *polymath* or even [multifaceted](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/multifaceted):

> 2: having many aspects, abilities, etc

Comment: Nonsense, muftifaceted has nothing to do with  “having many aspects, abilities, etc”; instead, it means having aspects of wearing civilian or casual dress when  military. ([1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mufti#Noun))

Comment: @jwpat7 thanks, it took me a couple of seconds to spot the typo and I was wondering what you were on about :).